# Command line file sorting, copying

Tags: command-line, file-sorting

Copied from my terminal . . .

```
dan@Silver:/media/dan/RAID/MUSIC$ grep -r '.mp3' ./ > cp *.mp3 /home/dan/Music/
grep: input file ‘./cp’ is also the output
```

I have a music collection on an NTFS volume that I want to sort, and transfer to a new Ubuntu setup.  The commands above were intended to search 6 or 7 directories deep ("cp -r" wouldn't), and copy ONLY those files that ended in .mp3.

I have no idea what grep is talking about.  Any help available to a newbie?

Comment: With this, you're writing the grep output to a file called cp. To use the command cp, you have to use the pipe operator: `grep ... | cp /home/whereever`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right command-line tool for this job is `find` e.g.

```
find -iname '*.mp3' -type f -execdir cp -t /home/dan/Music/ -- {} +
```

The `-iname` test will match case-insensitively i.e. `.MP3` as well as `.mp3` - I'm not sure if that's important on NTFS filesystems. You could use `-name` instead.

Comment: dan@Silver:~/Music$ du -h
71G

Worked like a charm!  Thanks to the Steeldriver, too!

Comment: @steel what's the meaning of `-- {} +` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj the `--` terminates the list of options to the `cp` command, which makes it safe in the (rare) case of filenames that start with a hyphen. Using `cp -t targetdir/ {} +` is more efficient than `cp {} targetdir/ \;` since the latter calls `cp` once for each file found: however it is less portable (the portable alternative would probably be to use `xargs`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean about sorting, unless you want to change the directory layout, but here's why it's not working...

Part of the problem is that by using '>' you're redirecting output of the grep command to a file called 'cp' instead of using a pipe '|' to the 'cp' command.

However the bigger problem is that your grep command is probably never returning (or perhaps returning nothing), as you're using `grep -r '.mp3' ./`  instead of `grep '.mp3' -r ./`  Also, I imagine grep is probably looking for .mp3 in the *content* of the files rather than the *file names*.

try:

```
cd /media/dan/RAID/MUSIC
find . -name '*.mp3'
```

if that lists all of the files you wish to copy, try:

```
find . -name '*.mp3' -exec cp --parents "{}" /home/dan/Music \;
```

the `--exec` runs a command for each file matched by find, the `--parents` preserves the full path of the file (otherwise all files would be copied into /home/dan/Music instead of /home/dan/Music/subdir1, etc..), `{}` refers to the currently matched file.  I've put quotes around it because audio files often have spaces in them. the `\;` is how you terminate the command for `--exec`

Hope this helps.  Even if it doesn't I highly recommend you look into the man page for find and possibly xargs, which are a powerful combination where you can pipe find's output to xargs

Comment: steeldriver's answer is probably better, although you'll definitely need to look at the man page if you want to learn how it works

Answer (score 0):

**Find custom bash function package:**

https://github.com/Kiran-Bose/supreme

download and install the deb file for debian based systems.

Functionality overview

(1)Open Apps
----Firefox
----Calculator
----Settings

(2)Manage Files
----Search
----Navigate
----Quick access

```
            |----Select File(s)
            |----Inverse Selection
            |----Make directory
            |----Make file
                                          |----Open
                                          |----Copy
                                          |----Move
                                          |----Delete
                                          |----Rename
                                          |----Send to Device
                                          |----Properties
```

(3)Manage Phone
----Move/Copy from phone
----Move/Copy to phone
----Sync folders

(4)Manage USB
----Move/Copy from USB
----Move/Copy to USB